# Código notificación desaparezca automaticamente

Tags: android, push-notification

Cuando recibo la notificación quisiera que desaparezca automáticamente

Aquí adjunto el código, en el que creo la notificación. Lo que quiero que suceda es que cuando reciba la notificación: baje, lo veo en la pantalla y después de unos segundos suba solo sin tener que interactuar con él.

```
    public void notificacion(String label, String autor,String destino) {

        NotificationCompat.Builder notifica = new 
       NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon((((BitmapDrawable) getResources()

                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)).getBitmap()))
                .setContentTitle("tittle")
                .setContentText(label)

                .setAutoCancel(true);


        Intent intnot = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intnot.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intnot.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intnot.putExtra("Destino", destino);

        PendingIntent intnotpend = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intnot, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        notifica.setContentIntent(intnotpend);

                   notifica.setFullScreenIntent(intnotpend, true);

        notifica.setContentIntent(intnotpend);


    }

        NotificationManager notyman = (NotificationManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notyman.notify(10, notifica.build());
     }
```

Comment: Quieres que desaparezca ? o que suba depués de mostrarse?

Comment: que suba después de mostrarse

Answer (score 0):

> Cuando recibo la notificación quisiera que desaparezca automáticamente

Para que una notificación desaparezca, tu puedes cancelarla mediante el método `cancel()` :

```
 mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

> Lo que quiero que suceda es que cuando reciba la notificación: baje,
>   lo veo en la pantalla y después de unos segundos suba solo sin tener
>   que interactuar con él.

Esto hasta el día de hoy no se puede realizar, las notificaciones se muestran en la barra de status, la forma de alertar sobre la llegada de una notificación es mediante vibración, sonido o el led indicador, pero solo puedes "bajarla" para ver su contenido si interactuas con ella.

Si deseas que se muestre la notificación y después de cierto tiempo desaparezca puedes usar un Handler para esta tarea. Como ejemplo este método.

```
  private void showCustomNotification(){
        final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
        int TIME = 10000; //10 segundos
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        final NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

        int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, getString(R.string.app_name), when);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR; //Do not clear the notification
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; // LED
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; //Vibration
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; // Sound

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("Java (lenguaje de programación)")
                        .setTicker("Java (lenguaje de programación)")
                        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                        .setContentText("Java es un lenguaje de programación de propósito general, concurrente, orientado a objetos que fue diseñado específicamente para tener tan pocas dependencias de implementación como fuera posible.");

        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        Log.i(TAG, "muestra notificación.");

        //Cancela notificación.
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Cancela la notificacion.
                mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
                Log.i(TAG, "Cancela notificación.");
            }
        }, TIME);
    }
```

Puedes ver que la notificación se crea y puedes ver un texto el cual es el definido en el método `setTicker()`, pero para ver el contenido necesita tu interacción, el método cancela la notificación automáticamente después de 10 segundos :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La verdad es que pensaba que si se podía hacer, ya que aplicaciones de terceros que tengo si realizan esa ejecución con sus notificaciones, tipo whatsapp o facebook, Voy a probar las 2 opciones a ver cual se puede ajustar mejor, gracias!!!

Comment: Hola ya lo he probado y si que lo realiza como quiero, la pega es que no quiero que desaparezca de la barra de notificaciones, ya que luego deseo poder pulsarla.Como lo podría hacer?